# ASP Email Validator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, email-validation

I have a textbox with multiple lines in it, each being an email address. I have a button that when clicked should read the emails from the textbox and validate that they are working emails (no spelling errors or anything). How would I go about doing something like this? For context the textbox is called emailBox

VB:

```
Protected Sub SaveButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Thank you all so much in advanced!

Comment: Define "working emails".  What specifically are you looking to validate?  That they are just in the format of an email address?  Or something else?  Also, which part has you stuck?  Reading from the text box?  Splitting the input into individual emails?  Performaing your validation?  Something else?  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Hi, so I'm very new at asp and vb. This is actually the first project I've ever done with them. By working emails I do assume correct syntax for an email. I dont know if there is a way to check that its an actual email, so for my purposes I believe just checking for syntax is fine. And Im confused about getting the emails from the textbox because it is multiple lines and testing them for validation line by line. If you know anything that can help, i would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there I'm guessing by spelling errors you just mean valid email syntax.

You could use a regular expression. Like this:

```
Protected Sub SaveButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    dim regexExpression As New Regex("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$")
    'get an array of emails
    dim emails = emailBox.text.Split(",")
    'loop through emails checking each one
    For Each email in emails
        dim valid = regexExpression.IsMatch(email)
        'do whatever with result
    Next
End Sub
```

you will need to import this too, add it to the top of your file:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

then the variable 'valid' will have a value of True or False that you can do what you like with.

I have edited my answer, assuming you can use a comma to separate your emails.

Edit 2: I can't guarantee the regex will work 100% correctly. Run your own tests, tweak it if need be or find/write another.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. This doesn't work exactly right because the textbox has multiple lines each being its own email address. Is there a way to add a loop somehow that tests each line using that expression?

Comment: Can you separate the email addresses by a comma and use the String.Split() method? Then loop through the array? e.g emailBox.text.Split(",") will return an array of strings.

Comment: I have updated my answer assuming you can separate your emails in your text box by a comma

Comment: I cant use the comma, my boss just wants one email per line and thats it. The textbox actually gets populated from a single string that has all the emails seperated by a ; . So the textbox gets one email per line. Then I type in new emails. Then when I click the save button it checks that all the emails are valid, and saves them back to the DB. So as is right now the emails are in the textbox split by a space (i used vbCrLF to make each a new line). Does your code for regex expression include emails like "FirstName.Lastname@company.com"? Where there might be a period in the middle of it?

Comment: So you could replace the comma in my code with a semi-colon before you remove them. Personally I think the design could be better, having them all in one text box is not ideal.

Comment: I agree that the design could be better. But I'm trying to make it exactly how he wanted it. If i put vbCrLf into the split statement it splits them up correctly. But it doesnt recognize it as an email because its a FirstName.LastName@company.com email. Is there a way to make your regex statement include emails like that as well? Thank you so much, i greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Try this one, Dim regexExpression As New Regex("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")

copied from https://regexr.com/2rhq7

Comment: Please upvote if my answer provides value or is helpful, I hope it has.

Comment: Yes it definitely helped. Thank you so much for your help, i greatly appreciate it!